# Get content of elements from the html code in preg_match_all

Tags: php

I have an old database where the articles are located. In each article description in the "text" field of MySQL there are links in which the parameters are included. I want to get them out using the preg_match_all function

Example element in description:

```
<a href="[xxxx][1] " cat_id="[xxxx][2]" tab-id="[xxxx]3">[xxxx][4]</a>
```

I wrote a code that does not work, how can I pull out only these elements, omitting the rest of the content?

my code:

```
<?php
$desc = '<a href="http://mywebsite.com" cat_id="156" tab-id="3">My name</a>';
preg_match_all('/<a href="(?P<href>.*)" cat_id="(?P<cat_id>.*)" tab-id="(?P<tab_id>.*)">(?P<name>.*)</a>/', $desc, $return); 
print_r($return);
?>
```

Comment: you also want the value "My name" ?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the "My name" content as well

Comment: the `/` for the closing tag should be escaped as such: `<\/a>` ([see it in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tWSO2b/1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$desc = '<a href="http://mywebsite.com" cat_id="156" tab-id="3">My name</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($desc);
$elm = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
echo $elm->item(0)->getAttribute("cat_id");
echo "<br>";
echo $elm->item(0)->getAttribute("tab-id");
echo "<br>";
echo $elm->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

That would give you:

```
156
3
My name
```

Comment: I needed it! Thanks

Comment: And how can I loop for $ elm = $ dom-> getElementsByTagName ("a");

Comment: @urbmake You can use for example a `foreach` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/4C9uh)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data='<a href="http://mywebsite.com" cat_id="156" tab-id="3">My name</a>';


preg_match_all("/(?:(?:\"(?:\\\\\"|[^\"])+\")|(?:\'(?:\\\\' | [^\'])+\'))/is", $data, $match);

echo '<pre>';

print_r($match);
echo(strip_tags($data));
```

The preg_match_all will look for every value that is enclosed in double quotes and create an array with them. The output is like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "http://mywebsite.com"
            [1] => "156"
            [2] => "3"
        )

)
```

For getting the name inside the html tags you can use the strip_tags function to remove every HTML code and get only the text of it. The output will be :

```
My name
```